# Spring transaction configuration

Tags: java, spring, interface, transactions, annotations

When configuring Spring transaction through xml, is it good to bind interfaces or concrete
 classes for transaction? I was thinking that we should have interfaces mapped for 
 transaction handling, but i found this from Spring documentation: 
 "The Spring team's recommendation is that you only annotate concrete classes with the 
 @Transactional  annotation".

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transaction boundaries are implementation details, therefore they should be specified by implementation rather than by interface.

For example, imagine that in some complex case you need to use programmatic transaction management (`TransactionTemplate`) rather than `@Transactional` for one of your methods. If you have `@Transactional` at interface level, it won't be possible.

Comment: Sorry that i got into @Transactional in my question. Actually thats a part i extracted from Spring documentation. My question is about declaring transaction through xml. In that way, should i bind interfaces or implemetation classes?

Comment: @user495939: This reasoning stays true for xml as well.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are contracts. Transactionality isn't (generally) part of a contract. It's an implementation detail. Hence @Transactional belongs on the implementation class, not in the interface.

Comment: Lets say we dont use annotations, and only declaring transactions in through xml. In this case, we can have both interface and class proxies right? which one is better? Thats my concern.

Comment: @user495939: As axtavt said, the same reasoning can be applied to XML-declared transactions. Instead of classes and interfaces, you have beans and types. You can consider that roughly the same rules apply.

Answer (score 0):

*@Transactional* annotation are not inherited from interfaces, so if you use a different method of proxying (such as *proxy-target-class=true* or *aspectj*) your real method will not be transactional.

See proxy-aop (for standard transactional annotation)
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies